# Dynamic component loading in Dotnet

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuke-build

We are using dotnet 6.The goal is to split implementation to following structure:

- Executable.Web1

  - ProjectReference Lib.Domain
- Executable.Web2

  - ProjectReference Lib.Domain
- Lib.Domain

  - IMyService
- Lib.Component.A

  - MyServiceA
  - ProjectReference Lib.Component.Dependency
- Lib.Component.B

  - MyServiceB
  - ProjectReference Lib.Component.Dependency

Executables loads correct component according to the configuration. I'm using `Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);` for that. It works, but I have troubles with build. I don't want to reference both `Lib.Component.A` and `Lib.Component.B` from executable project. I want to have a build dependency but not a reference. There is a `ReferenceOutputAssembly=false` options in csproj. That does exactly what I need. The projects `Lib.Component.A` and `Lib.Component.B` will build if you build the executable project. But it is not referenced. The problem is that it is not in the output bin folder. How to ensure that the build result is

Executable.Web1/bin

- Executable.Web1
- Lib.Domain
- Lib.Component.A
- Lib.Component.B
- Lib.Component.Dependency

Executable.Web2/bin

- Executable.Web2
- Lib.Domain
- Lib.Component.A
- Lib.Component.B
- Lib.Component.Dependency

Comment: Are you doing the assembly loading on your own instead of letting .NET do the job? If yes, why?

Comment: Yes, I need to load dll dynamically by configuration. Let say something like plugins. You can choose in configuration if you'll use `Lib.Component.A` or `Lib.Component.B` but not both of them